# Field automorphisms of extension generated by two coprime algebraic elements.

Tags: proof-verification, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and let $a,b$ be algebraic over $F$ with $[F(a) : F] = n$ and $[F(b) : F] = m$ coprime. Let $\sigma \in \textrm{Aut}(F(a,b)/F)$. Is it true that $\sigma(F(a)) = F(a)$ and $\sigma(F(b)) = F(b)$?

I tried letting $\alpha \in F(a)$ and considering the minimal polynomial of $\sigma(\alpha)$ over $F$ and looking at degrees, but this didn't help.

Comment: $gcd(n,m) = 1$ $\implies$ that $[F(a,b) : F] = nm$. maybe you can try seing  what the vector space $F[a,b]$ looks like, and see what are its field automorphisms ?

Comment: OP: do you know this to be true? Did you find it in a book or something?

Comment: I don't it's something I thought might be true.

Answer (score 1):

Try $a=\sqrt[3]{2}$, $b=\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$.

Note that $a,ab,ab^2$ are the three roots of $X^3-2$.  In particular, there is an automorphism sending $a$ to $ab$.

Comment: how is it supposed to answer the question ? here $[F(a) : F] = [F(b) : F]$

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. Nevermind...

Comment: @user1952009 $[F(a):F]=3$.  As I had written it, we had $[F(b):F]=4$.  But I made a mistake; I meant to let $b$ be a third root of unity, not a fourth root of unity.  It should now be correct, and we have $[F(b):F]=2$.

Comment: yes here $[\mathbb{Q}(b):\mathbb{Q}] = 2$, and before we had $[\mathbb{Q}(e^{i \pi / 4}) : \mathbb{Q}] \ne 3$ but $4$ since $e^{i \pi / 4}- (e^{i \pi / 4})^3  = \sqrt{2} \not\in \mathbb{Q}$ sorry

Comment: @user1952009 You're correct that it was a failure as an example.  There needs to be some interaction between the Galois groups.

Comment: @slade: do you actually know how to prove this? I've been struggling for a while and gotten nowhere.

Comment: @Vik78 The original proposition (that an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ must send $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$) is false; my answer gives a counterexample. If you want to prove my statement about the Galois groups, then it should be enough to extend $\sigma$ to the splitting field: if the Galois group decomposes as a direct product (no "interaction"), the proposition is true.

Comment: You're right. I also just realized that if F(a) is fixed by all members of Aut(F(a, b)/F), then Aut(F(a, b)/F(a)) is a normal subgroup. But in some cases we can pick b such that F(a, b) is a normal extension, so this implies that F(a) is also. If I had reasoned this way originally I probably would have been lead to your counterexample.